# IBM quantum computers gate delay values

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, decoherence

I am doing an state of the art study about the existing quantum computer technologies and one of the parameters of interest is the gate delay value, as it determines the time expected from a gate from such computer to make its operation, and consequently, it is important to see the coherence time that such computer presents.

I would like to know where can I find such values for the IBM quantum computers.

Answer (score 3):

The length of all backend basis gates is available from `backend.properties().gate_length`. For example

```
properties = backend.properties()
id_gate_length_qo = properties.gate_length('id', 0)
```

Comment: How do I select the computer I want?

Comment: Please see the section "Running circuits from the IBM Q account" in this [tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/fundamentals/1_getting_started_with_qiskit.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `backend.properties()` described above, you can go to https://quantum-computing.ibm.com, click a machine, then click "Download Calibrations".